# I have a question about defining a route for moving pages in flutter

Tags: flutter

I tried to define a route for page navigation, but as you can see, the following error occurs.

What's the difference between the DashBoardMain and MyProfileModify causing this error?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYCk0.png)

This is the code that is normally defined.

```
class DashBoardMain extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashBoardMainState createState() => _DashBoardMainState();
}

class _DashBoardMainState extends State<DashBoardMain> {
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _value = 0;

    return Scaffold(...);
  }
}
```

This is the code where the error occurs.

```
class MyProfileModify extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyProfileModifyState createState() => _MyProfileModifyState();
}

class _MyProfileModifyState extends State<MyProfileModify> {

  void  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget submitButton = new Container(
      child: new RaisedButton(
        onPressed: submitData,
        child: new Padding(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: new Text('Submit Data'),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the explanation of IDE is very clear. You defined MyProfileModify in two file and import both of resources. So you just remove unnecessary one or better way rename one class.

Comment: Thank u soooooooooooooooooooooooo much! It works perfect!!! Have a nice day :)